# How to Push an already exsisting working tree repository to a bare remote repository with TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am trying out Git with TortoiseGit. I already have a repository with working tree in my local drive `C:\WorkingSandbox`

I created a bare Git repository in my network drive `D:\GIT_Python_Repo.git`. Now how do I push the *WorkingSanbox* directory to my `D:\\` for safe keeping?

When I try to use Push - Remote -- Manage, I see the following window. What should I fill the fields (Remote, URL, Push URL, Putty key, etc?) with here?
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can name your remote "`origin`" (default remote to push to)

The URL and Push URL would be `D:\GIT_Python_Repo.git` (if it does not work, try `file:///d/GIT_Python_Repo.git`)

No need for putty key: this is not an SSH URL, just a [local one](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_local_protocol).